# How do I code a speed hack on Minecraft 1.10?

Tags: java, minecraft

So, I am trying to make a hacked client for Minecraft version 1.10 (just for the purpose of learning Java), but I have hit a bit of a block. I have been able to make many different kinds of hacks such as KillAura, Nuker, etc. but I can't seem to figure out how to increase the movement speed of a player. Again, I am just doing this to learn Java and to see how Minecraft works. Here is what I have tried so far (all refferences to mc are `Minecraft.getMinecraft()`):

Attempt 1:

```
public void onUpdate() {
    if (!this.getState()) return;

    if (mc.thePlayer.moveForward > 0.0F) {
        mc.thePlayer.moveForward = 20F;
    }
}
```

Attempt 2 (Some success, but exponential speed increase is unwanted):

```
public void onUpdate() {
    if (!this.getState()) return;

    if (mc.thePlayer.moveForward > 0.0F) {
        mc.thePlayer.motionX *= 2;
        mc.thePlayer.motionZ *= 2;
    }
}
```

Attempt 3:

```
public void onUpdate() {
    if (!this.getState()) return;

    if (mc.thePlayer.moveForward > 0.0F && mc.thePlayer.moveForward < 10F) {
        mc.thePlayer.motionX *= 2;
        mc.thePlayer.motionZ *= 2;
    }
}
```

Attempts 4+ were all different tutorials for Minecraft 1.8 on YouTube that I tried adapting to 1.10 (I will update with links to the different tutorials if needed)

**Update**
There are no errors in the code, no stacktraces that are created, I am just not getting the desired effect. With attempt 1 and attempts 4+, nothing changed the gameplay when the hack was activated. With attempts 2 and 3, the movement of the player was increased, but it was an exponential (might not be the correct word) increase that I could not limit. Neither of these are the desired effect, and I could not seem to get any sort of working code without causing the game to crash due to extreme world generation lag (due to the speed).

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S. Sorry for the long post

Comment: what is the problem? do you have any errors?

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem with that info. Maybe you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the initial value of mc.thePlayer.motionX if he is moving? If this is 1.0 for example, you could just do `if (mc.thePlayer.motionX == 1.0) mc.thePlayer.motionX = 2;` to double the speed.

Comment: @jimmycarr The default value depends on what the player is doing, and the code is so dense and cryptic that I can't read what it is when the player moves forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onUpdate() {
    if((mc.thePlayer.moveForward != 0 || mc.thePlayer.moveStrafing != 0)
            && !mc.thePlayer.isSneaking() && mc.thePlayer.onGround) {
            mc.thePlayer.jump(); 
            mc.thePlayer.motionX *= 1.4;
            mc.thePlayer.motionY *= 0.4;
            mc.thePlayer.motionZ *= 1.4;
    }
}
```

This code will check whether the player is on the ground, moving and isn't sneaking and then will increase their speed by 1.4x default and the y axis will be changed to make them jump but also allowing them to increase their speed even further as they won't be in the air for as long. This can also act as a bypass to some bad anticheats.

For newer versions (1.11+) use player instead of thePlayer